# No graphic eq in calf plugin eqalizer in Ubuntu Studio Disco Dingo

Tags: plugins, ubuntu-studio

The calf plugin Equalizer doesn't show the graphic of the frequency curve when added using Carla.  The controls are there just no eq curve.

[image: No eq curve!]

If I start the same plugin from Ardour, I have the graphic representation.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the UI bridge. See https://github.com/falkTX/Carla/issues/814